# How to get media url for each domain?

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I am writing a plugin that works on the command line interface (CLI) and it pulls the URLs of images according to the APP_URL. The problem is that I need to set the media repository for each domain. The SalesChannelDomainId is defined on the $context parameter. On the frontend, the images are shown according to the domain name.

However, if I automatically add the SalesChannelDomain URL, it will cause a problem for CDN users. Should I write service for this?

```
$imageLinks = [];
$criteria = new Criteria($mediaIds);
$criteria->addAssociation('translations');

$medias = $this->mediaRepository->search($criteria, $context->getContext());
foreach ($medias as $media) {
    $imageLinks[$media->getId()] = $media->getUrl();
}
```

$context has SalesChannelDomainId

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood your issue correctly but you may inject `Shopware\Core\Content\Media\Pathname\UrlGeneratorInterface` into your service and call `getRelativeMediaUrl` to get the relative path to the file. Then you can prepend the sales channel domains as you need them.

```php
$relativePath = $this->urlGenerator->getRelativeMediaUrl($media);
$absolutePath = $salesChannel->getDomains()->first()->getUrl() . $relativePath;
```

Comment: When Shopware loads media, "MediaLoadedSubscriber" is called and it saves media's links by domain name with addUrls function and urlGenerator.  While my plugin is retrieving medias, it retrieves the links of the product images with the domain name defined in APP_URL.  shopware-en.test/product-1 -> shopware-en.test/image-1.jpg  shopware-de.test/product-1 -> shopware-en.test/image-1.jpg If I use relative path and add the domain url, I will not be able to access the media url replaced by other plugins.   I hope I was able to explain my problem.

Comment: Sorry, I don't really get the idea for the use case. What other plugins are you referring to? Also you can just subscribe to the `media.loaded` event yourself, with a lower priority, so your listener is called after the other plugins did their thing. Then you can react to their changes. `MediaEvents::MEDIA_LOADED_EVENT => ['doSomething', -999]`